# Clean way of running virt-install with an iso file that's in your home directory that user qemu can't access

Tags: bash, permissions, kvm, qemu, libvirt

I have a script that automatically creates and runs a VM. That script is used by many people. You basically call the script giving it some information like what PCI or USB devices you want to pass through and which iso to use to install the OS and then the script runs `sudo qemu-system-x86_64` with the appropriate parameters.

So if you break it down, you could currently call my script like this:

```
./create-vm.sh /home/me/os-images/windows10.iso
```

And this works fine.

But now I want to take it a step further and use `sudo virt-install ...` instead of `sudo qemu-system-x86_64 ...` and that is causing major issues because with `virt-install` it can't access the iso file anymore. Presumably because it drops its root privileges and uses the `qemu` user even if I run it with sudo...

So now I have to make a difficult decision:

- Do I *move* the iso file to `/var/lib/libvirt/images`? (No because the user might need that file in the exact location where it is right now.)
- Do I *copy* the iso to `/var/lib/libvirt/images`? (No because the user might not have enough disk space and it just seems like a waste of resources.)
- Do I set `user = root` or `user = me` in `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`? (No, because that is a global setting that might mess up other qemu stuff the user is doing. - I have tried it though and it causes `libvirtd.service` to crash.)
- Do I add the group of the iso file to the qemu user? (No, because that could have unwanted side effects, potentially giving qemu more access in situations where the user wouldn't want it. - Nevertheless, I've tried it and it didn't work, presumably some SElinux magic is blocking it...)
- Do I change the owner of the iso file to `qemu`? (No, because that might have unwanted side effects. - Besides that, when I try it I still get permission denied errors, probably because of SElinux.)
- Do I mount the iso and make the mountpoint available to the qemu user? (No, because iso files can be very complex and some data will not be available in the mountpoint.)
- Do I mount the folder containing the iso? (No because the iso file would still have the same owner/group.)

I just can't seem to find a good solution. What am I supposed to do now? I really need some of the functionality that `virt-install` offers over `qemu-system-x86_64`.

Note: In reality there is not just one iso image, but also a floppy image, some other iso files containing drivers and an ACPI table file. I get permission errors for all of these files from `virt-install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `chown qemu:qemu $ISO` alone doesn't work is because `qemu` likely doesn't have search permissions for $HOME.

virt-install attempts to detect this situation and print a warning. virt-manager will go a step further and offer to try and fix, using roughly `setfacl --modify user:qemu:x $DIR` for every directory in the chain leading to the iso. This, coupled with libvirt chown'ing and selinux labeling the file automatically (the default behavior), should be enough to get the VM booting. Yes this behavior does have unwanted side effects but there's no way around it if you want the VM to be run as a different non-root user.

That said, if want you want is a VM that belongs entirely to one user, look at qemu:///session compared to the default qemu:///system libvirt URI. [Here's an explanation of the difference](https://blog.wikichoon.com/2016/01/qemusystem-vs-qemusession.html). Though you'll lose access to things like PCI passthrough in that case, stuff that requires libvirtd to have host admin access.

Comment: I definitely need PCI passthrough. I'd much rather have the VM run under the root user, (the same way as it does when I use `sudo qemu-system-x86_64`) than changing the users file permissions. Any ideas how I could achieve that?

Comment: If your machine is not a multi user machine, add user=root, group=root, security_driver = "none", dynamic_ownership = 0 in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf, restart libvirtd. That should all work, those features shouldn't be required for correct operation, they are security features

Comment: I already mentioned that in the third point of my question. I'm not the only one who'd be using that script. The script will be used by hundreds of people and I'd like to avoid their global settings because they may need them as they are right now.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood that. So if you need root requiring features like PCI passthrough, but can't change permissions on home, and can't change default libvirt config, then you can't use ISO in place in homedir. I'm afraid there's no way around it, you can't have all three at the moment. Honestly doing the equivalent of setting search permission ACL on the parent directory chain is not that invasive, we've done it in virt-manager for years and no one complains. Your script could prompt users before you do it so it's not a surprise. Just an idea

Comment: Well I dug a bit more and there may be a solution, add this to libvirt XML under <domain>: <seclabel type='static' model='dac' relabel='yes'><label>USER:USER</label></seclabel> replacing your username, or try root. With virt-install that's --seclabel type=static,model=dac,relabel=yes,label=USER:USER

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it, but unfortunately I still get permission errors when specifying root:root.

Comment: Interestingly I still get permission errors even after using setfacl like this https://pastebin.com/VWaAgARS (Do I have to use it on the root (/) directory and the file as well?

Comment: No / should always have world searchable permissions. To eliminate DAC permissions as the source, do chmod +x on every parent directory and set the iso to 777. If you still get errors after that, it's probably selinux or apparmor that is preventing access, try temporarily disabling that. Permission issues can be a pain to diagnose unfortunately

Comment: Even with selinux disabled (set to `Permissive`) and `chmod +x` on all directories and `chmod 777` on the file itself, I get `ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -acpitable file=/home/fedora/Projects/mbt/vm-files/ssdt1.aml: can't open file /home/fedora/Projects/mbt/vm-files/ssdt1.aml: Permission denied`. I don't think apparmor exists on my current distro (Fedora 34).

Comment: I also tried `sudo setfacl --modify user:qemu:rx .....` on every directory in the chain and checked with `sudo getfacl -e .....` to confirm that it actually worked which it did. An I mean it helped a bit because now I can access the file using `sudo runuser -u qemu -- less /home/fedora/Projects/mbt/vm-files/ssdt1.aml` without permission denied errors. But `virt-install` is still giving me the same error as mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: Let's follow up over email this is getting unwieldly in comments. I'm the primary virt-install dev FWIW. aindiscole@gmail.com. Please provide virt-install and libvirt versions, and pastebin full virt-install --debug output. We can come back here when we figure out the problem

Comment: err aintdiscole@gmail.com, sorry spelled my email wrong :/

Comment: Where would you place the ISO files to avoid all this in the more general case that you don't want to work around your way to letting Qemu read it from under the home directory? /var/lib/libvirt/images? what might be the best practice for a simple case of using virtual machines for testing the setup of projects on virtual machines?